# Monitor AJAX calls via cURL

Tags: php, ajax, curl

Is it possible to monitor a page's AJAX calls via cURL in PHP? For example, if I connect to a website that uses lots of AJAX to pull content, can I connect to the site via cURL, have it wait a couple of seconds until the AJAX requests are done and analyze the request that the site made?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "monitor" / "analyze" and what curl has to do with it. Can you make a real-life example?

Comment: Some sites use AJAX for search abilities, and I wanted to monitor their AJAX calls to see which URL their search capabilities connect to and what parameters they require so that I could use cURL to execute the searches without me having to do it myself through Firefox. I guess it isn't possible though =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) lets you easily monitor Ajax calls from the browser. All XMLHttpRequests show up in the Console and Net tabs with the ability to see both the request and response.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no.  **cURL is not a replacement for a browser.**  It simply downloads the HTML file.  The browsers will take that HTML, read for external scripts (js/css/images), download them, and then finally execute the JavaScript according to the browser's specific engine.

Answer (score 1):

Try Fiddler [FiddlerTool](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)